# The current timestamp is 0x5000. What is the smallest future timestamp that would win the game?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.5.x

[image]

The current timestamp is 0x5000.  What is the smallest future timestamp that would win the game?

Answer (score 0):

The code is doing a `mod` operation (%) with a divisor with value 2. It will return 0 when the dividend is even and will return 1 when the dividend is odd. This means that the `random` will actually either be 0 or 1. Since the timestamp represents the seconds that have passed since Jan 01 1970 (Epoch Unix Timestamp), and it's increased by 1, we could say that the chance of you getting 0 or 1 is 50%.

On average, half of the users that call that `play()` function will earn the reward.

But anyways, relying on the `block.timestamp` as a source of 'randomness' is not actually a good idea. Miners can tweak this value a little.

If a miner knows about a contract that is using the `block.timestamp` as a source of randomness to give rewards, the miner can tweak the timestamp a little so that it passes the function conditions, create a transaction and mine a block and get the rewards.

To get better random numbers in your contract, better try to use a service like [Chainlink VRF](https://docs.chain.link/docs/vrf/v2/introduction/).